# Easy modification to jQuery code to make use of more than one textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to change the following code to make use of all my 4 textboxes with id extra1, extra2,persons and tables?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#extra1').blur(function () {
        if ($.trim(this.value) == "") {
          $('#btnUpdate').attr("disabled", true);
        }
      else {
            $('#btnUpdate').removeAttr("disabled");
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `jQuery` [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) which will bind only one event handler but will act only on the element which triggers the `event`. Try this

Wokring **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bsTvt/1/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('formSelector').delegate('input[type=text]', 'blur', function () {
      if ($.trim(this.value) == "") {
          $('#btnUpdate').attr("disabled", true);
      }
      else {
            $('#btnUpdate').removeAttr("disabled");
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: @Giorkouros - Take a look at this, its very simple. Replace the appropriate form selector in the code thats it.

Comment: This is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mPuj9/1/ with your jQuery script. I still didn't manage to do it.

Comment: It is very well working, tried your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mPuj9/1/ too. Focus of any textbox, enter something and focus out of the textbox you will see the button gets enabled. What else do you need?

Comment: Please verify this and make it as an answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

```
  $('#extra1').blur(function () {
```

to

```
  $('#extra1, #extra2, #persons, #tables').blur(function () {
```

Answer (score 2):

The code modification would be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#extra1, #extra2, #persons, #tables').blur(function () {
        if ($.trim(this.value) == "") {
          $('#btnUpdate').attr("disabled", true);
        }
      else {
            $('#btnUpdate').removeAttr("disabled");
      }
    });
});
```

But, why not give all of them a class, and use that class as the selector? That way, you can easily add elements later without changing your Javascript.

Comment: That's true. Should I change it to `.myclass`?